# why is the date result in c# different then ActionScript?

Tags: c#

I want to get date utc in c# but the result in c# is different

ActionScript

```
var date = new Date();
date.fullYearUTC
date.monthUTC
date.dateUTC
```

Result

> 2020 3 9

in c#

```
DateTime.UtcNow.Year
DateTime.UtcNow.Month
DateTime.UtcNow.Date
```

Result

> 2020 4 09.04.2020 00:00:00

is UtcNow the wrong way?
thanxs for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionScript starts months at 0 for January, 3 for April, etc. whereas C# starts at 1 for January, 4 for April, etc. That explains the difference in the months.
The difference in output for the output for days in C# is that to get the day of the month in C# you say `DateTime.UTCNow.UTCNow.Day` for example, instead of `DateTime.UTCNow.Date`, which tries to output the whole date rather than just the day.

Comment: I tried this one 
DateTime.UtcNow.Year
DateTime.UtcNow.Month
DateTime.UtcNow.Day

my result is now `2020 4 9` so for the month I should minus the value? like `DateTime.UtcNow.Month -1`

Comment: It really depends what you're trying to do. If you're displaying the number to the user I'd probably leave as 4, as 4 would mean April in most people's minds, and 3 would mean March

Comment: ah okay so If I for example do an request to flash game (action script) then action script knows that 4 april in c# is 3 april in as?

Comment: If you're doing a request to a flash game, it probably won't know where the request is coming from, so adding 1 would probably be correct in this case. The easiest way would probably be to try it out and see what happens, unless the game has some kind of documentation :-)